# Xamarin List view not populating when using class

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm currently trying to learn Xamarin.forms and I'm stuck on the current part of my course.

I've created a list view manually, and was told to convert it to a "remote service" in a separate class.

When I did this, the list is no longer populating, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm getting zero errors when I compile.

The "remote service" that's placed in a class called "SearchServices.cs" code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ListExcercises.Models;

namespace ListExcercises.Services
{
    public class SearchServices
    {
        private List<Search> _searches = new List<Search>
        {
            new Search
            {
                Id=1,
                Location = "West Hollywood, CA, United States",
                CheckIn = new DateTime(2016, 9, 1),
                CheckOut = new DateTime(2016, 11, 1)
            },

            new Search
            {
                Id=2,
                Location ="Santa Monica, CA, United States",
                CheckIn = new DateTime(2016, 9, 1),
                CheckOut = new DateTime(2016, 11, 1)
            }
        };



        public IEnumerable<Search> GetRecentSearches(string filter = null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
                return _searches;
            return _searches.Where(s => s.Location.StartsWith(filter, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        }


        public void DeleteSearch(int searchId){
            _searches.Remove(_searches.Single(s => s.Id == searchId));
        }
```

The code behind for the view looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using ListExcercises.Models;
using ListExcercises.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ListExcercises
{

    public partial class ExcerciseListPage : ContentPage
    {
        private SearchServices _searchService;
        private List<SearchGroup> _searchGroups;

        public ExcerciseListPage()
        {
            _searchService = new SearchServices();

            InitializeComponent();

            PopulateListView(_searchService.GetRecentSearches());
            
        }
        //Create re-usable list grouping(populate list)
        private void PopulateListView(IEnumerable<Search> searches)
        {
            _searchGroups = new List<SearchGroup>
            {
                new SearchGroup("Recent Searches", searches)
            };

            listView.ItemsSource = _searchGroups;

        }
        void onItemTap(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var search = e.Item as Search;
            DisplayAlert("Tapped",
                "Costumer visited " + search.Location + " at " + search.CheckIn + " and left at " + search.CheckOut,
                "OK");
        }

        void listView_ItemSelected(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            listView.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        void Delete_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var search = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Search;

            //Delete local
            _searchGroups[0].Remove(search);

            //Update backend
            _searchService.DeleteSearch(search.Id);

        }

        void listView_Refreshing(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateListView(_searchService.GetRecentSearches(searchBar.Text));

            listView.EndRefresh();
        }

        void searchBar_TextChanged(Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateListView(_searchService.GetRecentSearches(e.NewTextValue));
            }

        
    }
}
```

And the XAML code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ListExcercises.ExcerciseListPage">
<StackLayout Padding="0, 40, 0, 0">
    <SearchBar Placeholder="Search..."
               Margin="0"
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
               x:Name="searchBar"
               TextChanged="searchBar_TextChanged"/>

    <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" IsGroupingEnabled="True" HasUnevenRows="True"
              GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}"
              ItemTapped="onItemTap"
              ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
              Refreshing="listView_Refreshing">
           

            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                         

                        <Label Padding="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Title}"
                               FontSize="21"
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>


            

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>

                            <MenuItem Text="Delete" Clicked="Delete_Clicked"
                                      IsDestructive="True" />

                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <StackLayout Padding="20, 0, 0, 0">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Location}" FontSize="20"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding CheckIn, StringFormat='{0:MMM d, yyyy}'}"
                                       TextColor="CornflowerBlue" FontSize="13"/>
                                <Label Text="-" TextColor="CornflowerBlue"
                                       FontSize="13"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding CheckOut, StringFormat='{0:MMM d, yyyy}'}"
                                       TextColor="CornflowerBlue"  FontSize="13"/>
                            </StackLayout>


                        </StackLayout>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>




        </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

I got to models besides the above posted code, one called Search.cs and one called SearchGroup.cs. Both are placed in Models folder in the project.

The code in SearchGroup looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ListExcercises.Models
{
    public class SearchGroup : ObservableCollection<Search> { 

        public string Title { get; set; }


        public SearchGroup(string title, IEnumerable<Search> searches)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the code in search looks like this:

```
using System;
namespace ListExcercises.Models
{
    public class Search
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
        public string Period
        {
            get
            {
                return String.Format("{0} - {1}",
                    CheckIn.ToString("MMM d, yyyy"),
                    CheckOut.ToString("MMM d, yyyy"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really hope someone can help and give me some pointers.

**TL;DR:**
Tried moving list creation to a separate document/class and now my list view doesn't populate with the information. So I get a view where most functionality is there, however alle rows are empty.

Comment: have you verified that the object your are using for ItemsSource actually contains the data you think that it does?

Comment: @Jason No I have not, what is the smartest way to do that?

Comment: use the debugger

Comment: @Jason Haven't used it with breakpoints and stuff before, but from what I just got I can only see that it's containing the header of the group, and not the list items.
 
Do you have any idea why? I will look in to it in the morning and get back if I find a solution, I've spend my entire evening reading through the code..

Comment: I'd suggest debugging `SearchGroup` - since you didn't post that code I can't offer specific advice

Comment: @Jason Thank you, I will try and do that in the morning. I just updated my question with the code from both Search and SearchGroup if anyone (or you) can spot any related issues.

Comment: You pass searches in the SearchGroup constructor but don’t actually do anything with it so it is just thrown away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your constructor needs to call the base constructor

```
public SearchGroup(string title, IEnumerable<Search> searches) : base(searches)
{
   Title = title;
}
```